# Can I add columns in listview in firemonkey?

Tags: listview, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I would like to display a list of items with columns. There is a way to do so in `Vcl` because it has columns property, but how to add columns in `FMX`?

Comment: Are you targeting desktop or mobile? What do you want to appears in the columns? What sort of UI are you looking for?

Comment: I am targeting both platform. I want to show  some items with their respective header. I want listview look and feel like TGrid.

Comment: Then use a grid control

Answer (score 2):

In firemonkey you can use ListBox. ListBox has property "Columns" and "Header"